# sha1sum reporting different hash value relative to openssl

Tags: hashsum

Why the difference in the following?

```
$ echo -n "foo" | openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac "key"
(stdin)= 9fc254126c2b1b7f106abacae0cb77e73411fad7
$ echo -n "foo" | sha1sum 
0beec7b5ea3f0fdbc95d0dd47f3c5bc275da8a33  -
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-hmac "key"` is what does it. Adding a HMAC is [*sort* of like salting the data](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29951/salted-hashes-vs-hmac). It's not quite the same but you're changing how the hash is calculated. Thus you end up with a different result.